# jQuery variable scope / call sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm having trouble understanding jQuery variable scope.

```
var myVar;

function getMyVar() {
    myVar = 'test';
}

$(window).load(function() {
    getMyVar();
});

alert(myVar);
```

This code will alert 'undefined' and I need it to show 'test' and I want to understand my scope issues here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that getMyVar isn't called until the window is loaded, while the alert is executed immediately.  So the alert happens before the variable is defined.  It isn't about scope, it's about the asynchronous execution of window load functions.

Comment: Okay, totally makes sense, this is for a jQuery plugin, does this mean I have to wrap the entire thing inside the $(window).load ?

Comment: That would be a way to fix it.

Comment: Ian: You should follow these guidelines:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

They will show you the awesomest ways to construct your plugins. Almost everything you do should be done on document ready and not immediately.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a scope issue.

`alert` is getting executed even before `window.load` event is triggered which is where the variable  myVar is assigned the value 'test'.

As per MDN Docs:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

Scoping is not limited to jQuery. Its how javascript defines scope is what rules here. jQuery is a library built on top of javascript.

Having said that, you're declaring a global variable which is accessible to everyone. However, the assignment happens after the DOM has completed loading. While the alert statement runs immediately.

If you move the alert inside of `.load` after call to `getMyVar()`, you'll see right value being output.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a scope issue.

`alert(myVar);` gets run before `getMyVar();`